# Changing language while typing in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that converts Arabic numbers to English while typing in an input, it's working on my desktop browsers, but when i try it on my mobile browsers it doesn't work, does anybody know why? here is the code:

```js
let map =  {
  '۰' : "0",
  '۱' : "1",
  '۲' : "2",
  '۳' : "3",
  '۴' : "4",
  '۵' : "5",
  '۶' : "6",
  '۷' : "7",
  '۸' : "8",
  '۹' : "9"
 };

function change(el){
  el.value = el.value.replace(/[۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹]/g, function(match){
    return map[match]
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="change(this)">
```

Comment: Would help if you gave us the exact specs of the mobile browsers you've tried using. Also, Android, iOS, both?

Comment: @RyanC google chrome IOS, i didn't try it on Android device

Comment: Perfect! You can debug Chrome on iOS if you [follow this article](https://medium.com/@nikoloza/how-to-debug-remote-ios-device-using-chrome-devtools-f44d697003a7). It will give you any error messages that occur just as if you were developing on your PCs Chrome application. Hopefully that can help you narrow down the problem. If not, you can come back to us with the exact error your getting in your console so that we can help you from there.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have the answer, you need to run on the object to find out if the character the user inserted in the input is equal to the "key" in the object.

see my code if it helps:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" onkeyup="change(this)" value="">

<script>
let map =  {
 '۰' : "0",
  '۱' : "1",
  '۲' : "2",
  '۳' : "3",
  '۴' : "4",
  '۵' : "5",
  '۶' : "6",
  '۷' : "7",
  '۸' : "8",
  '۹' : "9"
 };

function change(el){
  for (var key in map) {

          console.log(el.value.slice(-1));
        if (key == el.value.slice(-1)) {
             el.value +=  map[key]; // save the value as number
             el.value = el.value.replace(key,''); // clean all the "replaced" character
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```